# Unable to see chat box on IE10 in Metro mode on Windows 8, whilst a file download is underway

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

If you're downloading a file in IE10, in metro mode; it completely covers where the chat box would show, which makes it rather difficult to use.

[image]

Comment: That would probably be a good comment to the IE Beta team though. You should consider reporting it to MS.

Answer (score 5):

We don't support beta browsers, which IE10 currently is.

If the problem persists into the final release, then we'll address it.

Comment: https://twitter.com/#!/balpha/status/180540028764688386